# KeyPressedEvent to SetText for JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextarea, keylistener

I attempted to make a JTextArea in my Java.Swing application using NetBeans so that when I press the Enter Button. The JTextArea will display "BUTTON PRESSED".

Here is what I have:

```
private void keyPressedEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
{
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {
         System.out.println("HERE"); //For sanity check.
         txtArea.setText("BUTTON PRESSED");
         System.out.println("HERE AGAIN"); //For sanity check
    }
}
```

I noticed that the print statements are executing but the txtArea is not setting the text.

I did some research and believe that `evt.consume()` should be called somewhere, but I am unsure of how that works.

EDIT:
I tried putting `evt.consume()` in the `if-block` and it still did not set the text.

Adding the key listener like this:

```
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            KeyPressedEvent(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(59, 59, 59)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(175, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(40, 40, 40)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(164, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Look into key bindings instead of `KeyListener`. 3) There is no such class or method as `KeyPressedEvent` in J2SE.  Copy/paste these things rather than make them up.

Comment: Any errors/stacktrace when setText does not work?

Comment: There's no errors. I updated the OP. I used NetBeans to add a KeyPressed event by going RightClick => Properties => Add Key Pressed Event

Comment: Why are you using a KeyListener to monitor the enter key?you be should be using an ActionListetner. There is no guarantee that the "accept" action for the look and feel is enter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me. How are you adding the keylistener?

[image: test program screenshot]

```
public class TextAreaTest extends KeyAdapter {

  private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text Area Test");
  private JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TextAreaTest test = new TextAreaTest();
    test.go();
  }

  private void go() {    
    area.addKeyListener(this);
    frame.getContentPane().add(area);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {
         System.out.println("HERE"); //For sanity check.
         area.setText("BUTTON PRESSED");
         System.out.println("HERE AGAIN"); //For sanity check
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Just updated OP with how I added the key listener. It's auto generated using NetBeans (right click => Properties => Add KeyPressed). I made a small scale of this project and noticed that it seems  to work. Could it be because that I also have a keyTyped event?

Comment: *"Just updated OP with how I added the key listener."*  Did you try the code in *this* answer?  Did it work for you?  Dd you notice how all you had to do was fix the imports (presuming Netbeans did not do that automatically) before you could run it and see it?  Barring the imports, this code is an SSCCE, and it is shorter than the uncompilable code snippet in the edit to the question.  So to repeat myself (a little louder this time).. *For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).*